# Best practice when modifying plugins CSS

Tags: plugins, css

If i need to change CSS for a plugin, should i place the modified declarations with the plugins classes in my child themes style.css file or modify the plugins style sheet directly?

Comment: I'd say it depends what level of changes you need to make, if you're say changing the font size on two selectors, i'd personally stick something that small in the theme with `!important` declarations if necessary and be done with it. There's also option three with regard to the question, hijack the stylesheet enqueue and put your own in it's place.

Answer (score 1):

Any changes you make to the plugin's stylesheet will be overwritten when you update the plugin. Likewise with an edit to the theme's stylesheet. Even if you create your own stylesheet and enqueue it via `functions.php` you will have redo the enqueueing when you update. Of course, if this is a theme (or child theme) of your own creation that isn't a problem.

If you aren't maintaining your own theme, or child theme, there isn't a great way to do this, in my opinion. It would be nice if there were a global "user-functions.php" file. The closest thing to that that I can think of is a ["must use plugin"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), and I guess that is probably what I'd recommend.

1. Create a directory called `mu-plugins` in `wp-content`
2. Create a file in that directory and add your functions to it.

See the Codex page for details about Must-Use Plugins. They do not behave exactly like ordinary plugins.